# How to install a project into the file system with Maven

Tags: maven

I have a Maven project using the NAR Maven plugin to compile and link a C project. This works, but I can't seem to work out how to actually install and run the resulting project. The maven steps of "install", "deploy", etc. all seem to relate only to repositories - how do you take a project that has been installed into a repository and install it into the file system to actually run it? Eg. binaries into /usr/local/bin, libraries into /usr/local/lib, etc.